# React error 'Failed propType: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have some problem with React.js.
this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './containers/App';
import todoApp from './reducers';

let store = createStore(todoApp);
let rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

React.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        {() => <App />}
    </Provider>,
    rootElement
);
```

and runs the page, it saids:

> Failed propType: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement

this is the list of my related installed node modules:

- react 15.0.1
- react-redux 4.4.5
- redux 3.4.0

actually, i am currently learning React with Redux, so it is hard to me how should i do. i just followed tutorial on website(i can give a link, but it is not english) but it is just not working with that error message.
as i searched, someone said upgrade version of react and react-redux, but i installed latest versions.
any advice will be very appreciate it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [the doc](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#vanilla-react), you can just use a normal React element instead of a function inside `<Provider />`.

As a result, simply change your code to

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>
```

I think this has changed since react@0.14.

Answer (score 8):

The original question had a typo.   Your response is correct in the proper syntax.

However, the direct reason is that `<App />` needs to be on a separate line.

If you put it on the same line as `<Provider store={store}>` React/Redux tries to do more with it than it should.

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean here? Newlines shouldn't have any affect on how the JSX is interpreted. Most whitespace is stripped when bundled.

Answer (score 2):

I was brought to this and I simply forgot to provide a prop. I would say make sure that you are providing **all** the props that your component is using and that *should* fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but it was in case of an Overlay...the solution that worked for me is just removing the white spaces in between the component props .

for example :

```
<Overlay isVisible={global.ShowdispatchToDriverFlag} overlayStyle={{alignItems:"center",
                   justifyContent:"center",width:"95%",height:"95%",backgroundColor:"#ffffff"}}>
```

in the above there were white spaces between isvisible prop and overlaystyle removed the same and the error was gone.